# Android: JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview

I have following json generated by my website. I'm completely new with android programming. If possible tell me how to parse following json data to display in listview.

JSON:

```
  {
   "Category":[
      {
         "id":"14",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"3",
         "rght":"18",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:43:37",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:43:37"
      },
      {
         "id":"15",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"19",
         "rght":"28",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:44:10",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:44:10"
      },
      {
         "id":"16",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"29",
         "rght":"34",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:44:35",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:45:37"
      },
      {
         "id":"17",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"35",
         "rght":"60",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:44:52",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:45:53"
      },
      {
         "id":"18",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"61",
         "rght":"62",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:46:05",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:46:05"
      },
      {
         "id":"19",
         "parent_id":"2",
         "lft":"63",
         "rght":"70",
         "name":"Category Name",
         "icon":"",
         "created":"2012-04-21 23:46:19",
         "modified":"2012-04-21 23:46:19"
      }
   ],
   "success":1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the json array and get individual nested objects and arrays inside it one by one. Then use get(String key) method to get the value of individual strings inside the objects.

In your case, the code would be:

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_data.getString("Category"));
JSONObject temp;
for(i=0;i<json_array.length();i++)
{
temp = json_array.getJSONObject(i);

String id = temp.get("id").toString();
String parent_id = temp.get("parent_id").toString();
.
.
.
}
String success_value=json_data.get("success");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Gson by Google. Here is example. How to parse it to Array List

```
List<Category> categories = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Collection<Category>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jasonobject = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONArray jarray = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("Category");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) { ...}
```

check http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a 3rd party library like Jackson: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Then you can do something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonParser jp = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(jsonBody);
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jp);
```

Where jsonBody is your string. You can then use the get() method of JsonNode to extract your data in whichever way you find most useful for your purpose. There are plenty of examples on the Internet to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("Category");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google's JSON implementaion in Java.

GSON is just awesome. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/